# Draw a cross at the mouses location on a canvas, non persistently

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this bound to the mousemove event of my canvas:

```
function(e){        
    var contDiv = $('#current_system_map'); 
    var offset = contDiv.offset();
    x = e.clientX-offset.left;
    y = e.clientY-offset.top;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0,y);
    context.lineTo(595,y);
    context.moveTo(x,0);
    context.lineTo(x,595);
    context.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    context.stroke();   
}
```

and it works fine, to a point. The drawn cross is persistent, so when the mouse moves a new cross is drawn but the old one remains. I've tried essentially re-drawing the canvas but that cause the cross to be laggy and remain quite away behind the mouse.

So i need to know how to draw the cross and make it dis-appear without having to re-draw everything on the canvas

Comment: How are you redrawing the canvas? If you're using setInterval the  delay might be too high.

Comment: i had just dumped all the draw code into a function and then called it prior to drawing the cross

Comment: Have you considered using a CSS cursor (http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm)? If the default crosshair doesn't cut it, it's possible to use a custom .cur file instead.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/PgKEt/2/
This is the best that I can do.
If you try to use setInterval and such to animate it, it will keep redrawing even when it does not need to. So by doing this, you essentially only redraw when the mouse moves, and only draw 2 lines, instead of whatever content you want it on top.

In addition, if you have any detection such as mousedown and such, it has to be on whatever canvas is on the top, otherwise it will not detect them anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you draw something on the canvas you will have to redrawn the canvas contents to erase it.  I suggest you use an image element as a cursor and position it absolutely above the

Or you could try the old trick and draw the cursor in the canvas with `globalCompositeOperation='xor'`, then draw it again in the same place to erase it.  Afterwards you will need to restore `globalCompositeOperation` to `source-over`.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works fast enough for me in Firefox 3.6.8 to do in a mousemove event.  Save the image before you draw the crosshair and then restore it to erase:

To save:

```
savedImage = new Image()
savedImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
```

The to restore:

```
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.drawImage(savedImage,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to store it persistently, you can also take a look at SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Try

ctx.clearRect(0,0,YourCanvasHeight,YourCanvasWidth);

In my case I implemented a circle and every time the user clicks inside it, this instruction returns and deletes the previous points.

This is the complete code:

```
function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
        let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        let x = event.offsetX; //event.clientX - rect.left;
        let y = event.offsetY; //event.clientY - rect.top;
        drawPoint(canvas,x,y);

    };
        
function drawPoint(canvas,x,y) {
        if (canvas.getContext){
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fill();
        }
    };
                        
$(document).ready(function(){
        let canvasElem = document.getElementById("circle");          
        canvasElem.addEventListener("click", function(e)
            {               
                getMousePosition(canvasElem, e);                
            });
            
    });
```